# ColdFusion 2018 Bean-DAO-Manager OOP Logic Errors

Tags: oop, coldfusion, javabeans, dao

I am trying to learn about OOP in ColdFusion by recreating a proven Bean-DAO-Manager setup. In the example, I only use Create but the issue also exists for Read, Update and Delete.
I think I make some mistakes when passing the arguments. 
From index.cfc, I create an object from testBeanDaoManager.cfc, which holds the API. Here, the bean is created that should hold the properties. From there the manager is called which calls the db-query in the file testDAO.cfc.

The error states that the bean's method getName() was not found (more details at the end of the post).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Database and table: testBeanDao.APP.TESTBEAN

Files:
/index.cfm, /api/testBeanDaoManager.cfc, /logic/bean/testBean.cfc, /logic/dao/testDAO.cfc, /logic/manager/testManager.cfc

```
/index.cfm:
<cfscript>
    obj = createObject("component","api.testBeanDaoManager"); 
    add = invoke(obj,"addName", {ID=0, Name="Meo"}); 
</cfscript>
```

```
/api/testBeanDaoManager.cfc
component rest=true restpath="names" {
    remote any function gettestBean(ID){ 
        var nameManager = createObject('component', 'logic.manager.testManager');
        var nameBean = nameManager.getName(arguments.ID);
        return nameBean;
    }

  remote any function addName(numeric ID, string Name, restArgSource="path", any Data = {})  httpmethod="post" restpath="add/{id}" {
    var bean = gettestBean(arguments.ID);
    var nameManager = createObject('component', 'logic.manager.testManager');
    bean.setName(arguments.Name); 
    bean = nameManager.addName(bean);
    return bean;
  }
}
```

```
/logic/manager/testManager.cfc
<cfcomponent output="false" >

    <cffunction name="init" output="false" access="public" returntype="testManager">
        <cfset super.init(  gateway=createObject("component","logic.gateway.testGateway").init(),                                                   DAO=createObject("component","logic.dao.testDAO").init()) 
        />
        <cfreturn this />
    </cffunction>

    /**
     * Initializing Bean
     */
    <cffunction name="gettestBean" output="false" returntype="any">
        <cfset var bean = createObject("component","logic.bean.testBean") />
        <cfreturn bean />
    </cffunction>

<cffunction name="addName" output="false" returntype="any">
  <cfargument name="bean" required="true" />
  <cfset var dao = createObject("component","logic.dao.testDAO") />
  <cfset dao.insertName(bean) />

  <cfreturn bean />
</cffunction>
...
```

```
/logic/dao/testDAO.cfc
<cffunction name="insertName" returntype="any" output="false">
  <cfargument name="bean" type="any" required="true" />
  <cfquery name="local.result" datasource="testBeanDao" >
    INSERT INTO app.testBean (
        Name
    )
    VALUES (                     
        <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.bean.getName()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        )
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn local.result />
</cffunction>
```

```
/logic/bean/testBean.cfc
<cfcomponent displayname="testBean" output="false">

  <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="false" returntype="testBean">
      <cfset super.init() />
      <cfset variables.instance.ID = 0 />
      <cfset variables.instance.Name = arguments.Name />

      <cfreturn this />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="load" access="public" returntype="any" output="false">
      <cfargument name="ID" type="numeric" required="true"/>
      <cfargument name="Name" type="string" required="true"/>

      <cfset setID(arguments.ID) />
      <cfset setName(arguments.Name) />

      <cfreturn this />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="setName" returntype="void" access="public" output="false">
      <cfargument name="Name" type="string">
      <cfset variables.instance.Name = arguments.Name />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getName" returntype="string" access="public" output="true">
      <cfreturn variables.instance.Name />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="setID" returntype="void" access="public" output="false">
      <cfargument name="ID" type="numeric" required="true" />
      <cfset variables.instance.ID = arguments.ID />
  </cffunction>

  <cffunction name="getID" returntype="numeric" access="public" output="true">
      <cfreturn variables.instance.ID />
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Error Message:

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator.

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
The getName method was not found.
Either there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types or the getName method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce ambiguity.

The error occurred in C:/programs/cfusion/wwwroot/cfproject/logic/dao/testDAO.cfc: line 35
Called from C:/programs/cfusion/wwwroot/cfproject/logic/manager/testManager.cfc: line 45
Called from C:/programs/cfusion/wwwroot/cfproject/api/testBeanDaoManager.cfc: line 53
Called from C:/programs/cfusion/wwwroot/cfproject/index.cfm: line 85
33 :            )
34 :            VALUES (                     
35 :                    <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.bean.getName()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
36 :                    )
37 :        </cfquery>
```

Comment: You forgot to explain the issue you're having. If you're getting an error, please [edit] the question to include the error message.

Comment: My blind guess: `var bean = gettestBean(arguments.ID);` doesn't return an instance of `testBean`. You did not include said function in your post.

Comment: testBean.cfc is included in the code, please check again

Comment: Alex, yes, you are right, there were references to the testBean.cfc in the testManager.cfc and testBeanDaoManger.cfc that I did not post. I added them.

Answer (score 0):

*(too long for a comment)*

You are calling

```
var bean = gettestBean(arguments.ID);
```

which points to `gettestBean` of `/api/testBeanDaoManager.cfc`. This one does

```
var nameManager = createObject('component', 'logic.manager.testManager');
var nameBean = nameManager.getName(arguments.ID);
return nameBean;
```

but `logic.manager.testManager` doesn't have any `getName` function. Even if it had one, you would have to return an instance (the bean), which is kinda misleading for a method called `getName`.